# Расположить похожие объекты в массиве рядом

Tags: javascript

Я работаю с большими данными, вот упрощённый пример

```json
[
  { a: '0', b: '1' },
  { a: '0', b: '0' },
  { a: '1', b: '1' },
  { a: '2', b: '0' },
  { a: '0', b: '0' },
  { a: '0', b: '1' },
]
```

Мне нужно расположить похожие по некоторым свойствам записи рядом, например так (порядок не имеет значения)

```json
[
  { a: '0', b: '1' },
  { a: '0', b: '1' },
  { a: '0', b: '0' },
  { a: '0', b: '0' },
  { a: '1', b: '1' },
  { a: '2', b: '0' },
]
```

С небольшими данным справляется `Array.prototype.sort`:

```js
data.sort(({ a: a1, b: b1 }, { a: a2, b: b2 }) => a1 === a2 && b1 === b2 ? 0 : 1)
```

**Но вот с большими данными (100к+) это вообще не даёт результата (т.е. записи которые должны быть рядом находятся в разным местах массив)**

Оригинальная функция сравнения:

```
function compare<T>(a: T, b: T, compareKeys: (keyof T)[], dateField: keyof T) {
  const dateFiledA = a[dateField] as unknown as Date
  const dateFiledB = b[dateField] as unknown as Date
  return compareKeys
    .map((c) => a[c] === b[c])
    .concat([
      dateFiledA.getFullYear() === dateFiledB.getFullYear() &&
        dateFiledA.getMonth() === dateFiledB.getMonth() &&
        dateFiledA.getDate() === dateFiledB.getDate(),
    ])
    .every(Boolean) ? 0 : 1
}
```

Comment: Что значит не дает результата?

Comment: @SwaD Значит что записи которые должны быть рядом находятся в разным местах массива

Comment: @LIMPIX64 в смысле находятся в разных местах? Если вы про массив, то да ясно что они будут расположены по другому, метод `sort`, ведь **сортирует** массив, так он и должен работать.

Comment: @ΝNL993 К сожалению я не могу привести пример. При попытке отсортировать большой массив его вхождения меняются местами, но не все находятся рядом с другими похожими данными. Возможно что-то не так с функцией сравнения, сейчас добавлю в вопрос

Comment: Возможно, вам стоит описать некое обобщенное расстояние между двумя записями, и использовать алгоритмы кластеризации. Общие алгоритмы сортировки не сравнивают все записи между собой, поэтому добиться группировки вряд ли получится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вам надо правильно прописать фукнцию сравнения.
Вот пример для 150к элементов

```js
// Создаем массив в 150к элементов
console.time('add')
const y = [];
for (let i = 0; i <=150000; i++) {
  y.push({
    a: Math.round(Math.random() * 100).toString(),
    b: Math.round(Math.random() * 100).toString()
  })
}
console.timeEnd('add');

// Сортируем
console.time('go');
function microSort(c,d) {
  if (c > d) return 1;
  if (c < d) return -1;
  return 0
}

y.sort((q,w) => {
  if (q.a === w.a) {
    return microSort(q.b, w.b);
  }
  return microSort(q.a, w.a)
})

console.timeEnd('go')

console.log(y.slice(0, 10)); // Первые 10 записей
console.log(y.slice(-10)); // Последние 10 записей
```

Так же при сравнении надо учитывать тип данных при сравнении. Если есть вложенные объекты, их сортировку придется прописывать отдельно

Comment: `if (q.a > w.a) return 1;` это обязательно? Не все свойства я могу преобразовать в число. Например если это имя пользователя

Comment: @SwaD а не надо хоть к каком-то случае возвращать 0 ? :)

Comment: @LIMPIX64 функция сортировки должна возвращать число. 1, -1 и 0. 1 и -1 меняют местами элемнты, 0 не меняет. Если есть значения, которовые в явном нельзя сравнить, придется придумывать способ и сравнивать.

Comment: @splash58 Для точной сортировки, конечно должна, когда все элементы равны. Можно подтюнить последнее условие конечно

Comment: @LIMPIX64 По замечаниям в комментариях обновил ответ. Добавил "классическую" фукнцию сортировки, в которую передаются значения для сравнения и возвращается результат.

Comment: @splash58 Так красивее стало? )

Comment: @SwaD а то ж :)